# Quickbooks API PDF upload error: Maximum line length limit exceeded

Tags: api, callout, http, quickbooks

I'm trying to upload pdf file from Salesforce to Quickbooks attachments via Quickbooks API. It works fine with small files, but if file size exceeds 999 bytes, the following error appears:

An application error has occurred while processing your requestSystem Failure Error: Maximum line length limit exceeded

There is no such error, when I try do make such request from Postman.

HEADER:

```
httpReq.setMethod('POST');
httpReq.setEndPoint0'(https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<Realm_ID>/upload?minorversion=38');
httpReq.setHeader('charset','UTF-8');
httpReq.setHeader('Authorization' , 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
String boundary = 'MYBOUNDARY';
httpReq.setHeader('Content-Type' , 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
```

BODY:

```
--MYBOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_content_01"; filename="test first 11/07/2019 .pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
<my base-64 encoded file>
--MYBOUNDARY--
```

This code is run from Apex @future method. Are there some limits on Salesforce-Quickbooks connection or limits on callout length from @future maybe?

Comment: Hi @liza-chigrina I have the same problem in salesforce, can you resolved it?